# Faster Convergence for Riemann Zeta Function Sum?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

The Riemann Zeta function is defined as
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac 1{n^s}$$

for $s \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\text{Re}(s) > 1$.

To solve for the real and imaginary parts of $\zeta(s)$ in this range, let $s = a + bi$:

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n =1}^\infty n^{-(a+bi)} = \sum_{n =1}^\infty e^{-(a+bi) \log(n)} = \sum_{n =1}^\infty e^{-a\log(n)}e^{i(-b\log(n))}
\\ \implies \zeta(s) = \sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{\cos{(b\log(n))}}{n^a} - i\sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{\sin{(b\log(n))}}{n^a}
\\
\\ \therefore \text{Re}(\zeta(s)) = \sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{\cos{(b\log(n))}}{n^a}, \text{Im}(\zeta(s)) = -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin{(b\log(n))}}{n^a}
$$

With this, the complex output of $\zeta(s)$ can be visualized on a graphing calculator by translating $(x,y) \to (\text{Re}(\zeta(s)), \text{Im}(\zeta(s)))$. I did this myself [using Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sjmexr31yc).

However, graphing this is quite taxing since these sums converge very slowly—about as slowly as the harmonic series. It takes about 10,000 terms for the series to converge to at least 4 decimal places of accuracy.

Are there any more efficient ways to graph the real and imaginary parts of $\zeta(s)$ in this manner? Can we speed up the convergence of the sums somehow, so that they converge to their respective value with fewer terms?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Numerical_algorithms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Numerical_algorithms